# proof of the sum and product of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables

According to these two links,( [Link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239316/determine-the-pmf-of-the-multiplication-of-two-discrete-random-variables) and [Link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182962/probability-of-product-of-two-random-variables))
The distribution of multiplying two discrete random variables is given by :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Pr(T=t)&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr (X=x,Y=t/x)\\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr(Y=t/x|X=x)  Pr(X=x) \\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr(X=x) Pr(Y=t/x) \text{  ( if X independent Y )}
 \end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}
or as :
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
 Pr(T=t)&=\sum\limits_{x,y s.t. xy=t} Pr (X=x,Y=y)\\
 &=\sum\limits_{x,y s.t. xy=t} Pr (X=x) Pr(Y=y) \text{ ( if X independent Y)}
  \end{aligned} 
 \end{equation*}

Similarly for the sum of two discrete random variables ( [Link3](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Introductory_Probability_(Grinstead_and_Snell)/07%3A_Sums_of_Random_Variables/7.01%3A_Sums_of_Discrete_Random_Variables)) is given by :
\begin{equation*}
%  \scriptsize
\begin{aligned}
Pr(Z=z)&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr (X=x,Y=z-x)\\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr(Y=z-x|X=x)   Pr (X=x) \\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr (X=x) Pr(Y=z-x) \text{  ( if X independent Y )}
 \end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}

How can I proof that this is correct ?

Comment: I would say that what's written is proof enough depending on context

Comment: What is the point of writing it as conditional probability?